# Mongoose handle base64/ binary encode and decode

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm struggling to wrap my head around this and I've read all the posts I can find on it, but still am not making sense of the results I'm getting. I'm using react-signature-canvas which produces the output into a base64 string. I then seem to be successfully saving this through Mongoose with:

```
 let data = req.body.submittedSig.data;
    let split = data.split(',');
    let base64string = split[1];
    const buffer = Buffer.from(base64string, 'base64');

//...//
submittedSig: {
            data: buffer,
            contentType: plan.submittedSig.contentType
        },
```

this shows in the db as:

```
submittedSig
Object
data
BinData(0, 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJYAAABsCAYAAACICEudAAANIElEQVR4Xu2dSwgsRxWGjaj4CKjgxpVzjYrowidowOAoxMcmKgqi…')
contentType
"image/png"
```

When trying to decode, I've used several approaches such as .toBase64() - https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/functions/globals/#bson--binary-json- mongo function, but I get a 'not a function' error, and otherwise I've played with various combinations of Buffer.from(data, 'base64') and .toString('base64'). https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#static-method-bufferfromstring-encoding

```
const servicePlan = await ServicePlan.findOne({ _id: req.params.planId })
  // let sig = Buffer.from(servicePlan.submittedSig.data, 'base64').toString('base64');
  // sig = servicePlan.submittedSig.data.toString('base64');
  sig = servicePlan.submittedSig.data.toBase64();
            
  servicePlan.submittedSig.data = sig

  console.log("sig plan: ", servicePlan)
  res.send(servicePlan)
```

For any combination of the Buffer.from or .toString- whether used separetely or together, the console.logs the output as

```
data: new Binary(Buffer.from("6956424f5277304b ... 414141456c46546b5375516d4343", "hex"), 0),
```

and the return comes as:

```
 "submittedSig": {
        "data": {
            "type": "Buffer",
            "data": [
                137,
                80,
                78,
                71,
                13,
                10,
                26,
                10,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                13,
               ...
                ]
```

So as far as I can tell, the encoding takes it into binary, but all of my output is not decoding back to base64. Let alone, the end of the console.log of shows 'hex' which had me trying to convert the binary as if it was stored as a hex object, but that hasn't worked either. I'm sure its something simple that I just don't get with these, appreciate any guidance.

Comment: `base64` _encoding_ should just produce text, e.g., a string.  It will consume a bit more space, but you could just store the base64 encoded string in your collection.

Comment: @rickhg12hs most of what I was reading said to convert it to binary, that it would store better, take less space so that was the way I went. Considering this is just for signature images, the data size shouldn't be too much, I'll give that a shot

Comment: @rickhg12hs so when I do that, the string comes back unreadable - "u�Z�f�{�g���{�\"T��B��� ..." even on postman. Any idea why that would happen?

Comment: Nevermind, that was my bad, forgot to comment out a Buffer on the get req. Anyway, the base64 string itself barely takes up much space and certainly wont cause issues with Mongo's 16mb per doc limit, so this works for now. Thanks